# Watching parent with prop doesn't update during for loop

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components - `<my-component>` and `<grand-child-comp>`.

In my root there is a multidimensional object and my component watches it with prop.

```
<div id="app">
   <my-component v-bind:account-types='accountTypes'>
   </my-component>
</div>
```

In Vue debugger, I can see that my-component is getting and watching accountTypes object successfully. However, when trying to use it in `my-component's` template, it doesn't work.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: `
       <div>
          <grand-child-comp v-for="(account, index) in accountTypes" :key="index"></grand-child-comp>
       </div>
    `
}
```

Lastly, accountTypes object looks like:

```
{ 1 : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], 2: ['e', 'a', 'm'] }
```

Comment: With your fiddle in particular, you were passing `accountTypes` incorrectly to `my-component`.  https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/51204/

Comment: Ah. I found the problem. It was related with initialising accountTypes in the root. I was using `accountTypes: {}`. I tried to put pre-defined values and it worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you're doing the `v-for` and passing a property at the same time on the same element. You need to nest them so that the element the `v-for` is on wraps the `<grand-child-comp>`. [The documentation recommends a template for this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Template-v-for).

```
<template v-for="(account, index) in accountTypes">
  <grand-child-comp  :key="index"></grand-child-comp>
</template>
```

**UPDATE:** Based on what you said in your comments, what it sound like you really need is two nested for loops.

```
<!-- loop over account types -->
<div v-for="(accountId, values) in accountTypes">
  <h3>{{ accountId }}</h3>
  <!-- then loop over each individual value -->
  <ul v-for="value in values">{{ value }}</ul>
</div>
```

Your usage of components wasn't necessary. Components are only needed if you plan to use something in multiple places around your app. Just because the for loop is repeating the same elements multiple times doesn't mean you actually need a component there; The template inside the for loop would be enough.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the object idea? These keys imply the account number and the array is the values per account :/

Comment: I've updated my answer since the issue wasn't with your data structure but with your for loop and key assignment being on the same element.

Comment: I am very confused. I have prepared a fiddle. What I am trying to achieve is for loop through each array value but at the same time, know their keys

Comment: You mean you want two nested loops?

Comment: There is no problem with using `v-for` and setting a `key` on the same element. You would use a `template` if/when you wanted to render more than one non-nested element.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/51201/ Here it is. I'd be grateful for any help. @Bert so should I use a template for the grand-child instead of a component?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. You should only create components for stuff that actually gets reused in more than one place. A nested list of accounts and values isn't worth componentizing until you need it elsewhere in your app. Just use two nested for loops.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to do the nested loops. This is starting to stray really far from the original question and we shouldn't be treating this like a discussion forum.